# Access Session List in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

.aspx.cs:

```
List<SomeObject> items = whatever.getList();
```

`Session["records"] = items;`

If I access the Session in my Javascript file it gives me a string like

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SomeObject]'
```

.js function:

```
var records = '<%= Session["records"] %>';
```

How can I convert the session into an array?
Thanks

Comment: you can make a ajax call and get array of session

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through that array and print the right values:

```
var records = [];

<% 
    foreach(var item in (List<SomeObject>)Session["records"]) { 
%>

records.push('<%= item.PropertyName %>');

<% 
    }
%>
```

Now you got an array in your script with those values.

To get an array of objects like `{ Property1: "value1", Property2: "value2" }`, that stands for the same structur of your C# object, for example, you have use reflection.

Comment: Works fine, but how can I read the C# native code in my javascript file?

Comment: @user3441641 what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
I am not checking

```
<script>
    var someSession = '<%= Session["SessionName"].ToString() %>';

 </script>
```